# replacement for bootclasspath option in java

Tags: java, android, bootclasspath

I am trying to build an Android app manually just from the command line without using any kind of extra things, such as the build system (Gradle). I am following [this page](https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676).

But, I am stuck at compiling the Java source files.
Whenever I am issuing the command :
`javac -d obj -classpath src -bootclasspath E:/.android/sdk/platforms/android-10/android.jar src/com/example/hello/MainActivity.java`
*(My Android SDK is in **E:/.android/SDK** folder)*
I am getting
`error: option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 12`
I am using JDK version 12.0.2. I came to know that the **boot-class-path** option was removed since JDK version 9. So, how to compile the Java source files? What is the alternative to the **boot-class-path** option in JDK 12.0.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 9 and beyond don't support the **bootclasspath** option, but the bootclasspath can also be treated as a normal classpath. I had included the **bootclasspath** path with **classpath** and it worked.

`javac -d obj -classpath src -bootclasspath E:/.android/sdk/platforms/android-10/android.jar src/com/example/hello/MainActivity.java`

I just removed the `-bootclasspath` and included the path to android.jar into `classpath`.

`javac -d obj -classpath src;E:/.android/sdk/platforms/android-10/android.jar src/com/example/hello/MainActivity.java`